# How to parse nested EventGrid message?

Tags: python, json, nested, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I'm just learning about Azure Functions triggered by a Queue Storage event handler. In this case, Queue Storage is handling Event Grid messages.

**Question: How do I use Python to access the various values nested in `"body"` below?**

- Such as the value of `body/data/blobUrl`

**The Queue Storage message looks like this** (indented for readibility):

- `"body"` is the nested EventGrid message

```
{
    "id": "<big-long-guid>", 
    "body": "{
        \"topic\":\"/subscriptions/<big-long-guid>/resourceGroups/azureStorage/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/stgcool\",
        \"subject\":\"/blobServices/default/containers/cont-pics/blobs/profile_pic.jpg\",
        \"eventType\":\"Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated\",
        \"id\":\"<big-long-guid>\",
        \"data\":{
            \"api\":\"PutBlob\",
            \"clientRequestId\":\"<big-long-guid>\",
            \"requestId\":\"<big-long-guid>\",
            \"eTag\":\"0x8D94CE0B2F5CD71\",
            \"contentType\":\"image/jpeg\",
            \"contentLength\":35799,
            \"blobType\":\"BlockBlob\",
            \"blobUrl\":\"https://stgcool.blob.core.windows.net/cont-pics/profile_pic.jpg\",
            \"url\":\"https://stgcool.blob.core.windows.net/cont-pics/profile_pic.jpg\",
            \"sequencer\":\"00000000000000000000000000003730000000000000312a\",
            \"storageDiagnostics\":{
                \"batchId\":\"<big-long-guid>\"
            }
        },
        \"dataVersion\":\"\",
        \"metadataVersion\":\"1\",
        \"eventTime\":\"2021-07-22T07:17:00.8479184Z\"
    }", 
    "expiration_time": "2021-07-30T05:10:37+00:00", 
    "insertion_time": "2021-07-23T05:10:37+00:00", 
    "time_next_visible": "2021-07-23T05:20:37+00:00", 
    "pop_receipt": "cOQ8m5lN2QgBAAAA", 
    "dequeue_count": 1
}
```

**Here is the sample Function code that generates the above log:**

```
import logging
import json

import azure.functions as func

def main(msg: func.QueueMessage):
    logging.info('Python queue trigger function processed a queue item.')

    result = json.dumps({
        'id': msg.id,
        'body': msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'),
        'expiration_time': (msg.expiration_time.isoformat()
                            if msg.expiration_time else None),
        'insertion_time': (msg.insertion_time.isoformat()
                           if msg.insertion_time else None),
        'time_next_visible': (msg.time_next_visible.isoformat()
                              if msg.time_next_visible else None),
        'pop_receipt': msg.pop_receipt,
        'dequeue_count': msg.dequeue_count
    })

    logging.info(result)
```

**Tried:**

- Wrapping `msg.get_body()` in different iterations of `get_json()` and `json.dumps()` but received errors.

**Edit 1:**

- Changing `'body': msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'),` to `'body': json.loads(msg.get_body().decode('utf-8')),` converts the body to actual JSON which is nice.
- But how do I then access `['body']['data']['blobUrl'] in` result`?
- `type(result)` is `str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing this with the understanding that you're trying to update how you provide the `result` for `logging`. If what you're actually trying to do is parse it out of the poorly constructed `Queue Storage` message, let me know.

Given the example you gave as a dict:

```
d = {
    "id": "<big-long-guid>", 
    "body": "{
        \"topic\":\"/subscriptions/<big-long-guid>/resourceGroups/azureStorage/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/stgcool\",
        \"subject\":\"/blobServices/default/containers/cont-pics/blobs/profile_pic.jpg\",
        \"eventType\":\"Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated\",
        \"id\":\"<big-long-guid>\",
        \"data\":{
            \"api\":\"PutBlob\",
            \"clientRequestId\":\"<big-long-guid>\",
            \"requestId\":\"<big-long-guid>\",
            \"eTag\":\"0x8D94CE0B2F5CD71\",
            \"contentType\":\"image/jpeg\",
            \"contentLength\":35799,
            \"blobType\":\"BlockBlob\",
            \"blobUrl\":\"https://stgcool.blob.core.windows.net/cont-pics/profile_pic.jpg\",
            \"url\":\"https://stgcool.blob.core.windows.net/cont-pics/profile_pic.jpg\",
            \"sequencer\":\"00000000000000000000000000003730000000000000312a\",
            \"storageDiagnostics\":{
                \"batchId\":\"<big-long-guid>\"
            }
        }",
        \"dataVersion\":\"\",
        \"metadataVersion\":\"1\",
        \"eventTime\":\"2021-07-22T07:17:00.8479184Z\"
    }", 
    "expiration_time": "2021-07-30T05:10:37+00:00", 
    "insertion_time": "2021-07-23T05:10:37+00:00", 
    "time_next_visible": "2021-07-23T05:20:37+00:00", 
    "pop_receipt": "cOQ8m5lN2QgBAAAA", 
    "dequeue_count": 1
}
```

We can look at values in `"body"` like this:

```
d['body']['data']['api']
PutBlob
```

Unfortunately, if you try this you'll get a `TypeError` thrown at you for trying to use a `string` to try to access an index in another `string`. We use `string` objects as keys for `dict`, but not for indices of `string`. The reason you're getting thrown such an error is that the `"body"` "`dict`" is actually a `str`, not a `dict` (note the `"` on either side of the curly braces).

Fix this by updating your `json.dumps` for `'body'`:

```
    result = json.dumps({
        'id': msg.id,
        'body': json.loads(msg.get_body().decode('utf-8')),
...
```

---

Edit:

Rereading your question, it seems like what I called a `dict` in your example might still be a string when you're getting it. In that case you might have more problems because of `"body"` being poorly formatted.

If this is the case, you can clean up those pesky `"` marks around the `"body"` value by running:

```
message = message.replace('"{', '{').replace('}"', '}')
```

before reading it in:

```
d = json.loads(message)
```

Comment: Studying your response now.

Comment: Updating the `json.dumps` for `body` ended up being the fix. I was able to parse after that. Thank you!

Comment: @KieranMoynihan, please see Edit 1 above. Using `json.loads` for the  `body` object converted it to JSON nicely, but now I'm having troubles accessing the values inside `body`. Any hints here?

Comment: @SeaDude Turn the string result you’re trying to parse into a `dict` by calling `json.loads` on it. See the last line of my answer. Then you can access the elements like in another other `dict` (see the beginning of my answer).

Comment: Nice. This worked to access the nested values `aeg_body_blobUrl=json.loads(result)['body']['data']['blobUrl']`